# How to hide scrollbar track

Tags: html, css, angular, scroll, scrollbar

is there any way to hide the scrollbar track but not the thumb? It should look like this:

[image]

Its currently looking like this:

[image]

This is the actual css for the scrollbar:

```css
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}
* {
    scrollbar-width: thin;
    scrollbar-color: var(--dark-blue) var(--custom-white);
}
*::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: var(--custom-white);
}
*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: var(--dark-blue) ;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 3px solid var(--custom-white);
}
```

FINAL CODE:

```css
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 15px;
}
*::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: transparent;
}
*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background-clip: content-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accepted answer is not correct anymore, and was already misleading year ago when it was posted.

Overlay was NOT part of official CSS specification. I was supported only by webkit engine, was later deprecated and eventually REMOVED. Currently `overflow: overlay` acts as `auto` so it should NOT be used.

According to [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/css-overflow-overlay), current support is only 8%, and will be decreasing.

Now correct answer will be - it is not possible to achieve this effect with pure CSS, because there is no such properties for `overflow` or `webkit-scrollbar`.

If someone really needs that - JS must me involved. Of course there are ready to use libraries like [Simplebar](https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar).

Comment: correct, thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 5):

Just add `overflow: overlay;` to the `body` tag instead of `overflow: auto`.
both work the same but with OVERLAY your scrollbar will be on top of content just as you want.
Worked for me.

Comment: damn bro you arrived a year later and you still saved the day, just used it in a project and worked like a charm thx!

Comment: lol, I was looking for the same thing for a long time, when I found it. I was like "that's it?". BTW that was my first answer on stackoverflow

Comment: WARNING - overflow overlay is not supported anymore. Check my answer for details instead wondering why this does not work :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the background-color property to your ::-webkit-scrollbar and set it to transparent.

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 10px;
}
* {
    scrollbar-width: thin;
    scrollbar-color: var(--dark-blue) var(--custom-white);
}
*::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: var(--custom-white);
}
*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: var(--dark-blue) ;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 3px solid var(--custom-white);
}
```

Comment: didn't work, i also tried making all the var(--custom-white) to transparent, these are the background color

Comment: Try doing it without the * in the beginning of the line.

Comment: still nothing, i believe it can't be done with only css, i'll explore some external packages

Comment: It can be done with only CSS. I do it on my own projects. But I'm not exactly sure why it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, since i tried everything with CSS and nothing worked, i figured it would be best to use an external package that helped me achieve this very very easily.

I used [this library](https://github.com/MurhafSousli/ngx-scrollbar/wiki) which is suuper super easy to set up and use. All i had to do was install it and use the component. In the wiki they have an example of use and its very noob-friendly and customizable.

Answer (score 0):

```css
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
 } /* webkit browsers(safari, chrome) */

*{
    scrollbar-color: #404040b3 transparent; /*firefox*/
 }
```

This is what worked for me finally.

Answer (score -1):

easy answer:

```
*::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    display: none;
    background-color: var(--custom-white);
}
```